# Why my param is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to pass a param in url but my param is always null :

View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ReferenceSearch/cab", "ProductResultList"))
    {
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">test</button>
    }
```

The action :

```
public ActionResult ReferenceSearch(string reference)
    {
        ...
```

I did exactly the same in anonther place, and this one is working :

View :

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Login/cab/la", "Authentication"))
    {
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">testAuth</button>
    }
```

The action :

```
public ActionResult Login(string fromcontroller, string fromAction, string param)
    {
```

My routes :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Auth",
            "{controller}/{action}/{fromController}/{fromAction}/{param}",
            new { controller = "Authentication", action = "Login", fromcontroller = "", fromaction = "", param = "" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "ReferenceSearchAfterLogin",
            "{controller}/{action}/{reference}",
            new { controller = "ProductResultList", action = "ReferenceSearch", reference = "" });

    }
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: `@using (Html.BeginForm("ReferenceSearch", "ProductResultList", new { reference = "cab" }))` assuming your controller is `ProductResultListController`

Comment: And your `ReferenceSearchAfterLogin` route definition can never be hit because it will always go to the `Default` route

Comment: ah yes you right, always go to the default route ^^ thx

Comment: You should mark a correct answer below incase someone else comes along with the same problem.

Comment: Actually the one which worked for me was Stephen's but i cannot tick it as correct as it's a comment, i didn't try the others

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ReferenceSearch", "ProductResultList"))
    {
        <button name ="reverence" value="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">test</button>
    }
The action :

public ActionResult ReferenceSearch(string reference)
    {
       //reference has now the Value submit 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what method `BeginForm` should have:

```
Html.BeginForm(actionName, controllerName, routeValues)
```

The better way to pass any value in query string (or url) is to add data in routeValues part. `actionName` and `controllerName` should be used only to specific the Action and Controller where to send the request. So change your forms in this way:

```
Html.BeginForm("ReferenceSearch", "ProductResultList", new { @reference = "tab" })
```

In this way you shouldn't be any problems with routing.